# Can I use PostGIS for a custom world?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the need to store 3D objects in a user defined space but I am having difficulty with the idea of creating a user defined world with PostGIS. **Can I create a virtual world using PostGIS to leverage all of the spatial math functions and indexes without having to place my "world" on the surface of the earth?** I would be ok with this world existing at the center of the earth if I had to.

**Goals:**

- Store rectangular prisms in a user defined 3D space/coordinate system.
- Have sub-coordinate systems within another coordinate system
- Calculate intersections of said rectangular prisms and other spatial calculations.
- Load information from a CAD drawing into a database

Is this possible with PostGIS? There is so much information out there that it is hard to consume so I would appreciate any type of answer suggesting do-able but difficult, easily do-able, or go a completely different direction than PostGIS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Longitude and latitude will work on any spheroid. So unless you want to model the disc world, why not?

Comment: I want to model a warehouse as my world with physical entities inside that have their own coordinate systems. The idea is roughly this: the warehouse is as large a space that we care about, then within the warehouse there exists a machine. We want to relate the position of the machine relative to a point in the warehouse. After that, we want to relate a position of something inside the machine relative to a corner of the machine.

Comment: So I guess I don't really want to model a spheroid at all but a 3D plane.

Comment: If you want to model Euclidean space (3-dimensional coordinates, no curvature), you can use `geometry` in PostGIS, and you don't have to worry about coordinate systems. PostGIS is mostly targeted at two-dimensional maps, but there is some support for the third dimension. At worst, you may have to add some missing functionality yourself.